# How to get data in 1 row using below code

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4

i want to get data in 1 row here by keeping the corresponding patient_id iam getting data in 1 row but if i execute by giving input parameter of function _patient_id iam data is inserting into ams.ams_trans_integration_events table in 4 rows

elsif(_integration_type=34) then /*Patient Registration*/

```
        select row_to_json(a.*) from (
            select
                m.mpi_ref_id as "refId",
                p.patient_isactive as "patIsActive",
                p.patient_created_by as "patientCreatedBy",
                m.mpi_lk_external_mpi as "patientMpi",
                p.patient_first_name as "patientFirstName",
                p.patient_middle_name as "patientMiddleName",
                p.patient_last_name as "patientLastName",
                p.patient_gender as "patientGender",
                p.patient_email as "patientEmail",
                p.patient_birthdate as "patientDob",
                p.patient_mobile::varchar as "patientMobile",
                2 as "partnerId",
                p.patient_maritalstatus AS "patientMaritalStatus",
                p.patient_education_level AS "patientEducationLevel",
                p.patient_identification_mark AS "patientIdentificationMark",
                p.patient_is_estimated AS "patientIsEstimated",
                p.patient_salutation AS "patientSalutation",
                p.patient_blood_group AS "patientBloodGroup",
                p.patient_mother_tongue AS "patientMotherTongue",
                true AS "patIdentifierIsactive",
                i.pat_identifier_dl AS "patIdentifierDl",
                i.pat_identifier_uid AS "patIdentifierUid",
                i.pat_identifier_pan_no AS "patIdentifierPanNo",
                i.pat_identifier_passport AS "patIdentifierPassport",

                (select json_agg(patDetails)
                from (
                select patient_language_language_id AS "languageId"
                from xch.xch_transmap_patient_language
                where patient_language_pat_id = _patient_id and patient_language_is_active = true
                )patDetails) as "patientLanguageIds",


                (select json_agg(patPersnlDetails)
                from (
                select cp.pat_cnt_land_line_no AS "homePhone",
                cp.pat_cnt_mobile_no AS "mobile1",
                cp.pat_cnt_email_id as "email",
                cp.pat_cnt_land_line_no1 as "workPhone",
                cp.pat_cnt_mobile_no1 as "mobile2",
                cp.pat_cnt_mthd_of_cmctn as "mthdOfComm"



                from  xch.xch_transmasmap_patient_contact pc
                left join  xch.xch_transmas_patient_contact cp  on cp.pat_cnt_id = pc.pat_contact_cnt_id 
                where pc.pat_contact_pat_id = _patient_id and pc.pat_contact_cnt_type_id = 1 and pc.pat_contact_isactive = true
                )patPersnlDetails)as "patientPersnlDetails",


                (select json_agg(patMailingAddressDetails)
                from (
                select cp.pat_cnt_address AS "address",
                cp.pat_cnt_area AS "area",
                cp.pat_cnt_pincode as "pinCode",
                cp.pat_cnt_city as "city",
                cp.pat_cnt_state as "state"
                from  xch.xch_transmasmap_patient_contact pc
                left join  xch.xch_transmas_patient_contact cp  on cp.pat_cnt_id = pc.pat_contact_cnt_id 
                where pc.pat_contact_pat_id = _patient_id and pc.pat_contact_cnt_type_id = 4 and pc.pat_contact_isactive = true
                )patMailingAddressDetails)as "patientMailingAddressDetails",


                (select json_agg(patEmergencyCnt1Details)
                from (
                select cp.pat_cnt_first_name AS "firstName",
                cp.pat_cnt_last_name AS "lastName",
                cp.pat_cnt_relationship_id as "relationship",
                cp.pat_cnt_email_id as "email",
                cp.pat_cnt_land_line_no as "homePhone",
                cp.pat_cnt_mobile_no AS "mobilePhone",
                cp.pat_cnt_area AS "area",
                cp.pat_cnt_pincode as "pinCode",
                cp.pat_cnt_city AS "city",
                cp.pat_cnt_state AS "state",
                cp.pat_cnt_address as "address"
                from  xch.xch_transmasmap_patient_contact pc
                left join  xch.xch_transmas_patient_contact cp  on cp.pat_cnt_id = pc.pat_contact_cnt_id 
                where pc.pat_contact_pat_id = _patient_id and pc.pat_contact_cnt_type_id = 2 and pc.pat_contact_isactive = true
                )patEmergencyCnt1Details)as "patientEmergencyCnt1Details",

                (select json_agg(patEmergencyCnt2Details)
                from (
                select cp.pat_cnt_first_name AS "firstName",
                cp.pat_cnt_last_name AS "lastName",
                cp.pat_cnt_relationship_id as "relationship",
                cp.pat_cnt_email_id as "email",
                cp.pat_cnt_land_line_no as "homePhone",
                cp.pat_cnt_mobile_no AS "mobilePhone",
                cp.pat_cnt_area AS "area",
                cp.pat_cnt_pincode as "pinCode",
                cp.pat_cnt_city AS "city",
                cp.pat_cnt_state AS "state",
                cp.pat_cnt_address as "address"

                from  xch.xch_transmasmap_patient_contact pc
                left join  xch.xch_transmas_patient_contact cp  on cp.pat_cnt_id = pc.pat_contact_cnt_id 
                where pc.pat_contact_pat_id = _patient_id and pc.pat_contact_cnt_type_id = 3 and pc.pat_contact_isactive = true
                )patEmergencyCnt2Details)as "patientEmergencyCnt2Details"/*,

                (select json_agg(patTpaInsuranceDetails)
                from (
                select
                itp.pat_policy_type_id as "patPolicyTypeId",
                itp.pat_policy_proposer_relation AS "relationWithProposerEmployee",
                itp.pat_policy_ins_company_id AS "insuranceCompany",
                itp.pat_policy_ins_id AS "insurancePolicy",
                itp.pat_policy_ins_grp_policy AS "insGroupPolicy",
                itp.pat_policy_ins_valid_till AS "insPolicyValidTill",
                itp.pat_policy_tpa_company_id AS "tpaCompany",
                itp.pat_policy_tpa_id AS "tpaPolicy",
                itp.pat_policy_tpa_grp_policy AS "tpaGroupPolicy",
                itp.pat_policy_tpa_valid_till AS "tpaPolicyValidTill",
                CASE WHEN _enc_order_ids = 0 THEN 0 ELSE itp.pat_policy_id END AS "patPolicyId",
                itp.pat_policy_pat_enc_id as "policyPatEncId",
                itp.pat_policy_created_by AS "patPolicyCreatedBy",
                itp.pat_policy_isactive as "patPolicyIsactive"

                from  xch.xch_trans_patient_ins_tpa_policy itp
                where itp.pat_policy_pat_id = _patient_id and itp.pat_policy_isactive = true
                )patTpaInsuranceDetails)as "patientTpaInsuranceDetails"*/



            from    xch.xch_transmas_patient p
            left join xch.xch_transmasmap_mpi_link m on m.mpi_lk_xch_mpi=p.patient_mpi
            left join xch.xch_transmas_patient_identifier i on i.pat_identifier_pat_id=p.patient_id
            --LEFT JOIN xch.xch_transmasmap_patient_contact c on c.pat_contact_pat_id=p.patient_id and c.pat_contact_isactive=true
            --LEFT JOIN xch.xch_transmas_patient_contact pc on pc.pat_cnt_id=c.pat_contact_cnt_id and pc.pat_cnt_isactive=true
            --LEFT JOIN xch.xch_trans_patient_ins_tpa_policy itp ON itp.pat_policy_pat_id=p.patient_id
            where   p.patient_id= _patient_id)a into integration_;
```

iam getting 4 rows inserting into ams.ams_trans_integration_events table like below but i need to insert only 1 row tht is last row

```
{"refId":504,"patIsActive":true,"patientCreatedBy":218,"patientMpi":"2000000100000504","patientFirstName":"Aliya","patientMiddleName":null,"patientLastName":"T","patientGender":2,"patientEmail":"aliya@gmail.com","patientDob":"2000-01-02","patientMobile":"8496064235","partnerId":2,"patientMaritalStatus":null,"patientEducationLevel":null,"patientIdentificationMark":null,"patientIsEstimated":false,"patientSalutation":null,"patientBloodGroup":null,"patientMotherTongue":null,"patIdentifierIsactive":true,"patIdentifierDl":null,"patIdentifierUid":null,"patIdentifierPanNo":null,"patIdentifierPassport":null,"patientLanguageIds":null,"patientPersnlDetails":[{"homePhone":884422119900,"mobile1":8496064235,"email":"aliya@gmail.com","workPhone":9086747856,"mobile2":8843756874,"mthdOfComm":1}],"patientMailingAddressDetails":[{"address":"6/2/201,Near Hosur Road","area":"ITPL","pinCode":684869,"city":46246,"state":1710}],"patientEmergencyCnt1Details":[{"firstName":"Vamsi","lastName":"G","relationship":91,"email":"vamsi@gmail.com","homePhone":8899002244,"mobilePhone":9894689586,"area":"Shivananda Nagar","pinCode":898359,"city":46486,"state":1714,"address":"9/4/241,Near S.T.Joseph School"}],"patientEmergencyCnt2Details":[{"firstName":"Smitha","lastName":"D","relationship":108,"email":"smitha@gmail.com","homePhone":8895685787,"mobilePhone":9057806789,"area":"Madhura Nagar","pinCode":574768,"city":103826,"state":4152,"address":"4/2/760,Near Minerva School"}]}


{"refId":504,"patIsActive":true,"patientCreatedBy":218,"patientMpi":"2000000100000504","patientFirstName":"Aliya","patientMiddleName":null,"patientLastName":"T","patientGender":2,"patientEmail":"aliya@gmail.com","patientDob":"2000-01-02","patientMobile":"8496064235","partnerId":2,"patientMaritalStatus":null,"patientEducationLevel":null,"patientIdentificationMark":null,"patientIsEstimated":false,"patientSalutation":null,"patientBloodGroup":null,"patientMotherTongue":null,"patIdentifierIsactive":true,"patIdentifierDl":null,"patIdentifierUid":null,"patIdentifierPanNo":null,"patIdentifierPassport":null,"patientLanguageIds":null,"patientPersnlDetails":[{"homePhone":884422119900,"mobile1":8496064235,"email":"aliya@gmail.com","workPhone":9086747856,"mobile2":8843756874,"mthdOfComm":1}],"patientMailingAddressDetails":[{"address":"6/2/201,Near Hosur Road","area":null,"pinCode":684869,"city":46246,"state":1710}],"patientEmergencyCnt1Details":[{"firstName":"Vamsi","lastName":"G","relationship":91,"email":"vamsi@gmail.com","homePhone":8899002244,"mobilePhone":9894689586,"area":"Shivananda Nagar","pinCode":898359,"city":46486,"state":1714,"address":"9/4/241,Near S.T.Joseph School"}],"patientEmergencyCnt2Details":[{"firstName":"Smitha","lastName":"D","relationship":108,"email":"smitha@gmail.com","homePhone":8895685787,"mobilePhone":9057806789,"area":"Madhura Nagar","pinCode":574768,"city":103826,"state":4152,"address":"4/2/760,Near Minerva School"}]}


{"refId":504,"patIsActive":true,"patientCreatedBy":218,"patientMpi":"2000000100000504","patientFirstName":"Aliya","patientMiddleName":null,"patientLastName":"T","patientGender":2,"patientEmail":"aliya@gmail.com","patientDob":"2000-01-02","patientMobile":"8496064235","partnerId":2,"patientMaritalStatus":null,"patientEducationLevel":null,"patientIdentificationMark":null,"patientIsEstimated":false,"patientSalutation":null,"patientBloodGroup":null,"patientMotherTongue":null,"patIdentifierIsactive":true,"patIdentifierDl":null,"patIdentifierUid":null,"patIdentifierPanNo":null,"patIdentifierPassport":null,"patientLanguageIds":null,"patientPersnlDetails":[{"homePhone":884422119900,"mobile1":8496064235,"email":"aliya@gmail.com","workPhone":9086747856,"mobile2":8843756874,"mthdOfComm":1}],"patientMailingAddressDetails":[{"address":"6/2/201,Near Hosur Road","area":null,"pinCode":684869,"city":46246,"state":1710}],"patientEmergencyCnt1Details":[{"firstName":"Vamsi","lastName":"G","relationship":91,"email":"vamsi@gmail.com","homePhone":8899002244,"mobilePhone":9894689586,"area":"Shivananda Nagar","pinCode":898359,"city":46486,"state":1714,"address":"9/4/241,Near S.T.Joseph School"}],"patientEmergencyCnt2Details":null}


{"refId":504,"patIsActive":true,"patientCreatedBy":218,"patientMpi":"2000000100000504","patientFirstName":"Aliya","patientMiddleName":null,"patientLastName":"T","patientGender":2,"patientEmail":"aliya@gmail.com","patientDob":"2000-01-02","patientMobile":"8496064235","partnerId":2,"patientMaritalStatus":null,"patientEducationLevel":null,"patientIdentificationMark":null,"patientIsEstimated":false,"patientSalutation":null,"patientBloodGroup":null,"patientMotherTongue":null,"patIdentifierIsactive":true,"patIdentifierDl":null,"patIdentifierUid":null,"patIdentifierPanNo":null,"patIdentifierPassport":null,"patientLanguageIds":null,"patientPersnlDetails":[{"homePhone":884422119900,"mobile1":8496064235,"email":"aliya@gmail.com","workPhone":9086747856,"mobile2":8843756874,"mthdOfComm":1}],"patientMailingAddressDetails":[{"address":"6/2/201,Near Hosur Road","area":null,"pinCode":684869,"city":46246,"state":1710}],"patientEmergencyCnt1Details":null,"patientEmergencyCnt2Details":null}
```

Comment: which row out of four you want to get?..

Comment: actually iam getting in 4 rows like this

Comment: if you are getting 4 same rows, add `DISTINCT ` after `SELECT`

Comment: no my all 4 rows data is different but i want only last row data to come

Comment: so define the corresponding clause in where?..

Comment: how to define the corresponding clause in where?

Comment: you have `where   p.patient_id= _patient_id`, change it to smth like `where   p.patient_id= _patient_id and patient_isactive is true` or what ever you wanted attribute has what ever wanted value

Comment: no its not working     where  p.patient_id= _patient_id and p.patient_isactive=true

Comment: update your question with all four rows sample and clear explanation which row should remain please

Comment: no its not last row i want to insert only 1 row i.e.,1st row

Answer (score 0):

change

```
where   p.patient_id= _patient_id)
```

to:

```
where   p.patient_id= _patient_id and (select json_agg(patMailingAddressDetails)
            from (
            select cp.pat_cnt_address AS "address",
            cp.pat_cnt_area AS "area",
            cp.pat_cnt_pincode as "pinCode",
            cp.pat_cnt_city as "city",
            cp.pat_cnt_state as "state"
            from  xch.xch_transmasmap_patient_contact pc
            left join  xch.xch_transmas_patient_contact cp  on cp.pat_cnt_id = pc.pat_contact_cnt_id 
            where pc.pat_contact_pat_id = _patient_id and pc.pat_contact_cnt_type_id = 4 and pc.pat_contact_isactive = true
            )patMailingAddressDetails)->>'area' = 'ITPL')
```